android- The app crashes when I go to the gallery tab
tried to make a call button on a different layout from the navigation draver layout
GalleryFragment.java
   public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {

        private FragmentGalleryBinding binding;

        TextView textView2;
        ImageButton imageButton4;

        public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                                 ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            GalleryViewModel galleryViewModel =
                    new ViewModelProvider(this).get(GalleryViewModel.class);

            binding = FragmentGalleryBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
            View root = binding.getRoot();


            return root;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            imageButton4 = (ImageButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);
            textView2 = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textView2);

            imageButton4.setOnClickListener(arg -> {
                String phone_number = textView2.getText().toString();
                Intent phone_intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                phone_intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone_number));
                startActivity(phone_intent);
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyView() {
            super.onDestroyView();
            binding = null;
        }

    }

enter image description here
enter image description here
I recently started learning Android
I was looking for how to do it on a different layout, the code only came to this and crashes

Might help to post the stack trace. Unrelated to the issue - you don't need to use findViewById when you are using view binding, just get the reference to the view from the binding property.

@Philio
thank you very much I looked about binding and did it and now it works
